# how can I implement keras activation functionality using tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to change some keras code for neural network into tensorflow code. I picked some snippets using keras for deep sarsa like below.

whole keras code for model:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(30, input_dim=15, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(5, activation='linear'))
    model.summary()
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=self.learning_rate))
```

whole tensorflow code for model:

```
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([15, 30], -1., 1.))
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([30, 30], -1., 1.))
W3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([30, 5], -1., 1.))

b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([30]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([30]))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5]))

L1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W1), b1)
L1 = tf.nn.relu(L1)
L2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(L1, W2), b2)
L2 = tf.nn.relu(L2)
model = tf.add(tf.matmul(L2, W3),b3)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(model,Y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(cost)
```

But I found the scale of model output is very different between them.
    For example, the output of below keras code is [ 0.4208471  -0.58310926  0.00578364  0.09069238 -1.1442541 ], And the tensorflow is [  9.947895   39.215603  -23.376497   21.344461   -7.0058045]. The point is that keras performance is much better than tensorflow code.

My question is exactly what it is doing in keras model.add with linear activation. I guess some kind of normalization is done. I did rando_uniform to initialize wights but I am not sure random_normal is better than it.
Anyway I want to know exactly and how to change it into the tensorflow code.

```
[keras] 
model.add(Dense(5, activation='linear'))

[changed with tensorflow] 
W3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([30, 5], -1., 1.))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5]))
tf.add(tf.matmul(L2, W3),b3)
```

I tried to use tf.keras.activation.linear but still seems like it is a little different.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow equivalent of Dense is tf.layers.dense:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense.
In your case, it would be:

```
L1=tf.layers.dense(x,30,activation=tf.nn.relu)
L2=tf.layers.dense(x,30,activation=tf.nn.relu)
model=tf.layers.dense(x,5)
```

You are probably noticing the difference in performance difference due to issues in initialization. Both default to xavier initialization I think. If you aren't going to add batch normalization, He initialization might help though.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I wonder how a layer.dense function is working , I mean, How does it initialize variables like wight and bias , and normalize input/output of the layer. I want to understand it exactly.

Comment: Check out: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initializers.   
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope